# Requiring mongoose singleton after fetching from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, require

I'm trying to build a singleton with mongoose to store my app config in the database, so instead of building a schema and model and exporting the latter with `module.exports` I'm fetching the config then exporting it, yet all I get is an empty JSON.

Here's my code for the config model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var configSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ad: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Ad'
  },
  max_users: Number
});

var configModel = mongoose.model('Config', configSchema);

configModel.findOne()
  .populate('ad')
  .exec((error, result) => {
    if (!error) {
      if (result) {
        module.exports = result;
      } else {
        var default_config = new configModel({
          ad: null,
          max_users: 100
        });
        default_config.save();
        module.exports = default_config;
      }
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  });
```

In the route, I'm only requiring the file and using it in a route

```
var config = require('../models/config');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json(config);
}
```

Please note that dynamically requiring the module in the route scope hasn't produced the problem.

Is it because `require` couldn't recognize exported variable in the asynchronous task ? Is there a proper way to handle this issue ?

Comment: `require` in CommonJS is synchronous. You can't define it asynchronously. Try defining a file with no specific `module.exports` and requiring it in another file will give you a `{}`.

Comment: @zeronone If so, I have to call a synchronous fetching function. Why does it return the fetched object when I call `require` from within the route scope ?

Comment: nodejs is inherently asynchronous. When you `require` it will just execute the file synchronously, but the callback that you are passing to `exec` function is executed at a later point. You can export a function which accepts a callback and internally calls the `findOne` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` in CommonJS is synchronous. Try defining a file with no specific `module.exports` and requiring it in another file will give you a `{}`

The following might work.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var configSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ad: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Ad'
    },
    max_users: Number
});

var configModel = mongoose.model('Config', configSchema);

module.exports = function (cb) {
    configModel.findOne()
        .populate('ad')
        .exec((error, result) => {
            if (!error) {
                if (result) {
                    module.exports = result;
                } else {
                    var default_config = new configModel({
                        ad: null,
                        max_users: 100
                    });
                    default_config.save();

                    cb(null, default_config);
                    module.exports = default_config;
                }
            } else {

                cb(error);
                //throw error;
            }
        });



}


// In your routes

var config = require('../models/config');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    config(function(err, val) {
        if (err) {
            // send back error
        } else {
            res.json(val);
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Adding the details you mentioned in the comments to your answer would make it even better.